# How to upgrade from iTunesLibrary in Catalina

Tags: itunes, macos-catalina, apple-music

I have an app that that uses the iTunes XML file to access the local library of songs. With the upgrade to Catalina the only way to do this is to manually generate the XML file, which is something I'd rather not ask of my users.

I did think of trying to see if the iTunesLibrary framework still works, but on my 2 Macs with Catalina installed the framework no longer contains the header files.

I've scoured the internet but found nothing that that will fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the instructions in the MacOS Developer documentation were wrong. In Catalina the framework is included standard and not in a separate folder, so it's easy to just include the framework and build